# How multi threading is used in piano apps?

Tags: java, midi, android-music-player, synthesizer, piano

I am trying to make a piano app for my desktop PC. I have tried to do this by using clips in Java and mapping all the sounds of a piano to specific keys on my keyboard by using multi threading. But the end result is not good. There are delays between starting a sound and pressing a key on my computer keyboard. Also the program lags a lot as I have made 88 threads for every key.

Do you know about how the piano apps that we use in phones are able to play multiple sound or notes without lagging or delays??

Comment: This question is definitely too broad but, anyway, I'm pretty sure that on mobile playing sounds is getting delegated to some low level sound handler and it decides whether the sound should be still played or not. I don't believe that any "thread for every button"approach is right and I'm almost sure that such applicants are not using multithreading at all

Comment: I also think that multi threading is not the solution but if multi threading is not used then how is it possible to play multiple sound/notes but pressing multiple keys?? Can you please help me?

Comment: With 88 threads, it's no wonder you have lags. Take a look at https://virtualpiano.net as an example. When you press a key, the sound starts. It doesn't end when the key is released - it takes at least 1 more second to finish. Maybe a number of threads should be equal to the number of keys pressed simultaneously. You wouldn't physically be able to press 88 keys at the same time. When say 3 keys are pressed, your program could count them, create 3 threads and play 3 sounds at the same time.

Comment: This is likely too broad for Stack Overflow. For discussion and guidance, seek a forums site such as CodeRanch.com.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of [VMPK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vmpk/), a virtual MIDI controller for desktop computers using Linux, Windows or macOS. It is open source, so you can download the C++, Qt5 based, sources and study/modify/hack them as you see fit. I've included some synthesizers, like the Sonivox EAS which is the Android OSP synth, but as any MIDI controller, you may use different MIDI synths. Threads are woven, but not one for each piano key. The number of keys is fully configurable, with a maximum of 128 MIDI notes. If you have any concrete question, I am available here to answer.